# Can I use my serial receipt printer as an emergency console?

Tags: kernel, printing, serial-port

I recently came into possession of a serial receipt printer and I would like to know if I could use it as an emergency print-out console for the following purposes:

- Kernel Panic (Stack Traces)
- Any errors
- Failed login attempts (includes sudo attempts)
- Root Access granted (through SUDO or other)

This is for a headless server. I would like to have a printed report instead of having to SSH in all the time and check `n+1` different logs.

Also, it would just look uber nerdy and cool.